# 7 inches long 4-40 screw

Tags: screws

I have been looking all over to find 7 inch long 4- 40 screws.

I found McMaster carries threaded 4-40 rods that are 8 inches long but these are not screws.

I know they do exist as I found one just lying around (image) but haven't been able to find a vendor.

Could someone help me find 7 inch long 4-40 screws.

If not, what would be a good way to turn 4-40 threaded rods into makeshift screws?  there won't be too much strain on the screw so im not worried about the strength.

[image]

Comment: They can be used for securing insulation, so that may be something to check.

Comment: Fastenal?.......

Comment: I would call that a bolt or a machine screw. Maybe that will help with your search.

Comment: To clarify: you are asking how to get a 4-40 threaded rod with a head on it that could be used with a slotted (or Phillips) screwdriver? Would you be OK with a screw with a hex head on it instead? If so, maybe two nuts tightened against each other on the end of the rod? Would you be open to soldering/brazing something on the end of the rod to form the head?

Comment: Or just one nut, held in place with LockTite or cyanoacrylate cement.

Comment: Old question with no responses to requests for more info, plus asking for shopping advice. VtC.

Answer (score 1):

A threaded 4-40 rod with a cap nut/acorn nut on one end would be similar to a screw.

[Acorn Nut Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acorn_nut)